# ES6 nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using promises and I am stuck with an issue, that is more a question of Best Practice.

I have a function that returns a promises resolving into an object (validated object) :

```
validate(req.body, bodyValidationSchema)
```

I have another function, creating an object in the database from the validated data and returning a promise resolving into the created object :

```
db.model.create(validated_data, other_parameters)
```

However, I can't just chain those functions using them such as :

```
validate(req.body, bodyValidationSchema)
.then(validated_data => db.model.create(validated_data, other_parameters))
.then(console.log)
```

Because, the last line will not print the created_object but a Promise resolving into the created object.
Therefore I have to do something like this, nesting the promises :

```
validate(req.body, bodyValidationSchema)
.then(validated_data =>
  db.model.create(validated_data, other_parameters)
  .then(console.log)
)
```

Is there any better way to do that ?
Also, if I replace the console.log by an async task and add another ".then()" not after that task but after the bigger one, it will not wait for that last task (I don't know if that is very clear...)

Thank you very much,
Giltho

**EDIT**: Here is the actual code that is showing issues

```
function createEmailView(req, res) {
  validate(req.body, emailCreationSchema)
  .then(validatedBody =>
    db.Email.create({ email: validatedBody.email, userLogin: req.user.login }))
  .then(email => validate(email, emailSchema, { stripUnknown: true }))
  .then((validatedEmail) => { console.log(validatedEmail); return validatedEmail; })
  .then((validatedEmail) => {
    res.status(201).json(validatedEmail);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error instanceof Sequelize.ValidationError || error.isJoi) {
      res.status(400).json(makeStandardErrorOfValidationError(error));
    } else {
      res.status(500).json(error);
    }
  });
}
```

If I try printing the "email" on the 3rd line, it is not a plain object but a promise resolving into one.
Therefore the validation doesn't work and just strips everything off...

Comment: *"However, I can't just chain those functions using them such as"* That should work. Are you using native promises?

Comment: Returning a promise from the callback passed into `then` will resolve that promise down the chain so the code you have there should work.

Comment: What happens if you do, instead of `console.log`, `console.log.bind(console)`?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is; if `create` returns a Promise it should be fine.

Comment: It should ?
Well now that you ask, the "validate" function is an async function promisified using bluebird's Promise.promisify and db.model.create is a function from Sequelize, certainly using native promises...

Comment: I'm editing the post to put the actual code it will be easier

Comment: If db.Email.create() returns a promise, then by passing it into Promise.resolve() you're wrapping it in another promise. So you should get rid of the Promise.resolve call for starters.

Comment: Yep sorry, it was a wrong copy/past, a try I made, but it is still not working

Comment: Like others have said, if your promises are Promises/A+ compliant, it is not possible that a `then` callback gets called with a promise as argument. That promise would have been resolved automatically before the `then` callback is called with the promised value. Can you show in your question what is logged exactly, and the code with which you have promisified `validate`?

Comment: I feel so f***ing dumb !!!
What I read as beeing a promise is actually a weird Sequelize model instance....
Sorry for wasting your time guys, thank you very much for your help....
Should I delete the post ?

Comment: @Giltho better - answer it yourself with what you learned and how you ended up solving it. Also, I warmly recommend async/await if you're on modern Node.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry about this but in the end I just mistook a Sequelize Model instance for a Promise.
I didn't have a promise given in parameters, therefore everything was good I just had to take the plain object from that instance

```
email.nodeValues
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score -4):

How about this?

```
validate(req.body, bodyValidationSchema)
.then(validated_data => {
    return db.model.create(validated_data, other_parameters);
})
.then(console.log)
```